# Dell E5580 Bios doesn't see bootable usb drive containing iso of 17.10

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install ubuntu 17.10 onto a Dell Latitude E5580 from a usb stick onto which I've burned the 17.10 iso using gnome-disks.   I've done exactly the same thing with the 16.04 iso and it worked fine (and still does).    The problem is that when I hit F12 and boot options come up, the stick containing the 17.10 iso is not seen.   When I do *exactly* the same thing with the usb stick containing the 16.04 iso, bios sees the stick under UEFI options, and I can boot to the stick.    As far as I can tell the two sticks have the same structure.    I've tried the same thing on two almost identical Dells, and the problem is the same on both.   I've also loaded the 17.10 iso onto a different usb drive, with the same problem.

One difference that I do notice is that the 17.10 iso is on a usb3 drive while the 16.04 iso is on a usb2 drive.     Could that possibly be the source of the problem, and if so, why?    Isn't usb3 supposed to be better?

Here's the output of fdisk -l. sdb1 contains the 17.10 iso, and sdb2 contains the 16.04

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x97f903c8

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     8064 60555263 60547200 28.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.8 GiB, 4007657472 bytes, 7827456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     8064 7827455 7819392  3.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

When I mount the drive sdb1 containing the 17.10 iso, all of the ingredients for booting seem in place.    Here's the content of the mount point:

```
simon@E5580:/mnt/usb>lt
total 76
-r--r--r-- 3463 Jan  5 12:55 md5sum.txt
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:55 boot/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:55 EFI/
dr-xr-xr-x 4816 Jan  5 12:55 isolinux/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:55 casper/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:55 install/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:55 .disk/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:54 dists/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:54 pics/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:54 pool/
dr-xr-xr-x 2048 Jan  5 12:54 preseed/
-r--r--r--  229 Jan  5 12:54 README.diskdefines
lr-xr-xr-x    1 Jan  5 12:54 ubuntu -> ./
```

Could somebody please suggest why my BIOS is not seeing the sdb1 drive?

Comment: Copied == burned?

Comment: sorry, I've edited the original, yes burned